# Combining multiple filters on querysets with django-filter

Tags: django, django-filter

Say, I have the following two Django models:

```
class Author(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Book(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    pages = models.IntegerField()
    author = models.ForeignKey(Author)
```

With `django-filter`, how can I write a `FilterSet`, that allows me to filter somewhat like:

```
Author.objects.filter(
    (Q(book__name__contains='How') & Q(book__pages=100)) |
    (Q(book__name__contains='Why') & Q(book__pages=50))
)
```

That is, I want to have a set of filter Fields, that are all applied to a related model and that I can combine. In my case, that set contains many more fields, so a custom `MultiValueField` is probably not really applicable.

Is there any standard way to solve this using `django-filter`, or should I implement my own filtering logic in the view?

Comment: What would the request querystring look like here? How would you differentiate the two sets of `Q` objects that you want to filter by?

Comment: `?book_name_1=How&book_pages_2=100&book_name_2=why&book_pages_2=50`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to keep this in the `FilterSet`, rather than pushing back up to the view, your best bet is to override the `qs` property and add the multi-value filtering logic there.

(A field with a custom `method` provides validation but still only takes a single value — so you'd need to pull the others from the `parent` anyway — as such, overriding `qs` seems clearer.)

Comment: I thought so, and decided that just doing it manually in the view with a standard django form would be an easier and more readable solution. However, your answer is still the correct way to go with `django-filter`, so I'll accept it.

Comment: Yep, fair enough. Django Filter's scope is "common filtering problems" — uncommon ones may still require doing it by hand. :-)